# TypeError at / Field 'id' expected a number but got ... django

Tags: python, django

Hello to all the programmers, I am a Django Developer, when I run my site without an account, the server got this error: TypeError at /
Field 'id' expected a number but got <SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x0000025D3D8E2F90>>.

My views.py is:

```
def homepage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        print("ok")
        user = request.user
        posts = Posts.objects.all()
        sortedk = sorted(posts, key= lambda f: f.lan(), reverse=True)
        comments = []
        pictures = []
        com = []
        comments_pictures = []
        for i in sortedk:
            lst = []
            id = i.id
            poste = Comments.objects.filter(post_name_id = id)
            com.append(poste)
            num = len(poste)
            prf = Profile.objects.get(id = i.writer_id)
            pictures.append(prf.avator)
            comments.append(num)
            for comment in poste:
                idh = comment.author_id
                kk = Profile.objects.get(id = idh)
                lst.append(kk.avator)
            comments_pictures.append(lst)
        print(comments_pictures)
    
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = CommentForms(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
            
                ns = form.save(commit=False)
                ns.author = user
                ns.post_name_id = int(request.POST.get("pk")[0])
                ns.save()
                return redirect('home:homepage')
        
        else:
            form  = CommentForms()
        cont = {
            "user":user,
            "posts":sortedk,
            'comments':comments,
            "pictures":pictures,
            "pos":com,
            "form":form,
            "comment_pictures":comments_pictures,
        }
        return render(request, 'home/home.html',cont)
    else:
        return render(request, "home/home.html")
```

Please help me in it.

How can I fix it?
Is there anyway?

Comment: Please, share the full traceback. Normally the Django error page has a function to turn the error in a text format that includes settings, traceback, etc.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], that includes the full error traceback, any code relevant to the traceback that you have written and doesn't come from Django itself.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are encountering is likely due to trying to get the id attribute of `i.writer_id` when `i.writer_id` is a `SimpleLazyObject` representing an AnonymousUser object. You should ensure that `i.writer_id` is not an AnonymousUser before trying to fetch the profile using `Profile.objects.get(id=i.writer_id).`

```
if hasattr(i.writer_id, 'id'):#or any method you want to verify i.writer_id
    # Check if i.writer_id has an 'id' attribute
    prf = Profile.objects.get(id=i.writer_id.id)
    pictures.append(prf.avator)
else:
   pictures.append(None)  # Set a default value or handle accordingly
```

Comment: There's no way you'd get an `AnonymousUser` object from something coming from a queryset unless you did something really wrong. I don't believe `i.writer_id` really is the issue.